# How to update React state once useMutation is done?

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I add an user to an api with react-query's useMutation hook. It works. Now, I need to add the new user to my array of users, which is in my state.

I know I'm supposed to query all the users with useQuery and then use onSuccess inside useMutation to modify the cache. But in certain cases, I don't fetch the users with useQuery, so I need to update a local state as I would do with a normal promise.

For the moment, I simply check if the prop "success" is true and if so, I update the array. But it only works on the second click. Why and how to fix this?

It seems the success condition inside onAddUser() is only reached on a second click.

```js
export default function App() {
  const { updateUser } = userService();
  const { update, loading, error, data, success } = updateUser();
  const [users, setUsers] = useState(allUsers);

  const onAddUser = async () => {
    await update(newUser);
    if (success) {
      return setUsers((users) => [...users, data]);
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        {users.map((user) => (
          <div key={user.id}>
            {user.name} - {user.job}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
      {loading && <div>sending...</div>}
      {error && <div>error</div>}
      <button onClick={() => onAddUser()}>add user</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Here is also a sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/usemutation-test-co7e9?file=/src/App.tsx:283-995

Comment: I think it's because of the async nature of the query. When you're doing the update() in side the `onAddUser`, it evaluates asynchronously, and therefore the success is true only the next time. Try adding `const update = await update(newUser)`, and evaluate `update.success` in the next line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `success` prop returned from `updateUser` (I assume this is somehow the result returned by useMutation) will only update on the next render cycle. Functions will still keep the reference to whatever they closured over, even if you have an async await in there. This is nothing react-query specific, this is just how react works.

I would suggest to use the `onSuccess` callback of the mutation function, or use `mutateAsync` and check the result, though you have to keep in mind to catch errors manually if you use `mutateAsync`. You can read about `mutateAsync` [here](https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/mutations#promises), I'm gonna show you a `mutate` example:

```
const { mutate, loading } = useMutation(() => ...);
const onAddUser = () =>
    mutate(newUser, {
        onSuccess:  (newData) => setUsers((users) => [...users, data]);
    });
  };
```

also, please don't violate the rules of hooks. You can only call hooks from functional components or other hooks (=functions that start with `use`), but in your codesandbox, you call `useMutation` from the `updateUser` function ...

Comment: Thanks! However, I prefer not to use useMutation or useQuery in my components since I prefer to separate concerns. In my opinion, api issues should be handled in an api service. Is this rule of hook just a "code of conduct" rule or something that can cause bugs & crashes? I've used useQuery & useInfiniteQuery with the same pattern and never had any issues.

Comment: Yes, the preferred pattern is to abstract that away into custom hooks - just name your service `useUserService` and you’re good. Since your service uses hooks (useQuery, useMutation, ...) you _cannot_ call it outside of react components and other custom hooks anyways.